# How to forcefully remove MySQL and MariaDB from Ubuntu 16.04, without `apt-get` and `dpkg`?

Tags: mysql, dependencies, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04, dependency-management

By wrong uninstalling *MariaDB*, I've lost working instance of *MySQL* and *MariaDB* in my *Ubuntu 16.04* system...

I've broken the dependencies so much, that I can not uninstall or install *MySQL* or *MariaDB*, using `apt-get`, or `dpkg`...

All the following commands failed:

```
apt-get [install -f] [update] [remove] [purge] [autorove] [clean] [check]
```

and options with `dpkg` such as:

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql
```

also don't help me.

Manually downloading the package and attempting to install from a local file did not help.

For each installation, uninstallation or other attempt, I get almost the same result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not installed
 mariadb-server-10.0 : PreDepends: mariadb-common (>= 10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not installed
                       Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (>= 10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not installed
                       Breaks: mysql-server
 mariadb-server-core-10.0 : Depends: mariadb-common (>= 10.0.34-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.22-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Is there any different way to permanently remove any traces and remnants of *MySQL* and *MariaDB* from the operating system, so that I can reinstall *MySQL* itself?

I need to working with *MySQL*, but I can't reinstall the operating system.

Please help me.

Comment: It is probably better to address the question to https://serverfaul.com. Run `dpkg --audit` to find what is broken. Then run `dpkg --list|grep -i mysql` and `dpkg --list|grep -i mariadb`, look at the first (status) column and, optionally, inspect detailed status for some of packages with `dpkg-info -s <name-of-package>`. Then you can try to remove found mysql/mariadb related packages with `dpkg -remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package-list>`. As a way around you can always run mysq in docker container without mysql being installed.

Comment: @YuriLachin Thank you for your help, please insert the content of your comment as an answer to this question so that I can give you reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

God exists! :D

The problem was solved by entering:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

without any other parameters

and later displaying all packages via:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb
sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

and removing problematic packages in the right order:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove package_name
```

After the complete removal of all problematic packages, I could re-install *MySQL* without any problems...

Thank you @YuriLachin for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably better to address the question to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Run:

```
dpkg --audit
```

to find what is broken.

Then run:

```
dpkg --list|grep -i mysql
```

and

```
dpkg --list|grep -i mariadb
```

Look at the first (status) column and, optionally, inspect detailed status for some of packages with:

```
dpkg-info -s <name-of-package>
```

Then you can try to remove found *mysql/mariadb* related packages with

```
dpkg -remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package-list>
```

As a way around you can always run mysq in docker container without mysql being installed

Comment: Tank you a lot!